# JavaScript Body.json() on response loses nested arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

```
import 'whatwg-fetch'
```

The incoming response looks like this (grabbed from proxy):

```
"data": {
    "category_tree": [
        {
            "category_id": "1",
            "name": "A",
            "children": [
                {
                    "category_id": 2
                    "name": "B, child of A",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "category_id": 3,
                            "name": "C, child of B",
                        }
                    ]
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the handler works like this:

```
.then( response => response.json())

.then( json => dispatch({
    type: RECEIVE_DATA,
    data: json
}))
```

But by the time the response.json() promise resolves, the data has already lost all of it's nested arrays:

```
"data": {
    "category_tree": [
        {
            "category_id": "1",
            "name": "A",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas for having this not happen?

**Edit:** the response header I am getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Thu, 12 Apr 2018 09:38:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.15
```

**Edit2:** request code currently looks like this:

```
const fetchCategories = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_CATEGORIES_REQUEST
        })

        return fetch(
        `${SERVICE_API_BASE_URL}/api/categorytree?ope_flg=1`)
            .then(
                response =>  response.json(),
                error => console.log("error in fetch cat", error)
            )

            .then(
                json => console.log(json) || dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_CATEGORIES_RESPONSE,
                    categories: json
                })
            )
            .catch(
                ex => console.log("parsing failed", ex)
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: From the documentation `fetch('/users.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(json) {
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  }).catch(function(ex) {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
  })` - check what output you get in the console. Also notice the `catch` block

Comment: @TncAndrei Thanks for the response friend, I've edited the question to add the response headers. Do you think if I changed the Content-Type on the response I could just treat it as JSON as you are saying?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, Sorry, I got it wrong the first time with the JSON thing. I think you should use a `catch` block to see if you have any errors down the line. A fiddle with your code would be much helpful

Comment: @TncAndrei I added the request code -- Is there a good place to get the fiddle working with a library like whatwg-fetch? (catch block isn't getting triggered)

Comment: Alright, it's working! What it needed in the end is to first be interpreted as text, and then have that text parsed as json. So first `response.text()` and after that `JSON.parse(text)`

Comment: Great! So this was the issue `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response needed to be first interpreted as text, and then parsed as JSON. From the mozilla docs on ["the body mixin for the fetch API"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body):

> Body.text() Takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It
>   returns a promise that resolves with a USVString (text). The response
>   is always decoded using UTF-8.

Perhaps `.json()` was failing because of some encoding issue? I did try changing the Content-Type to `Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json` but that didn't seem to help.